# How to create Cookies with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

How to set cookies for this script?

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("a.switch_thumb").toggle(function(){
      $(this).addClass("swap"); 
      $("ul.display").fadeOut("fast", function() {
        $(this).fadeIn("fast").addClass("thumb_view"); 
         });
      }, function () {
      $(this).removeClass("swap");
      $("ul.display").fadeOut("fast", function() {
        $(this).fadeIn("fast").removeClass("thumb_view");
        });
    }); 

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't need jQuery for this (though there there are several `$.cookie` plugins). You can just use the [three cross-browser functions found on quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html#script):

```
function createCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

function eraseCookie(name) {
    createCookie(name,"",-1);
}
```